# Слово "дурак"

Tags: этимология

Когда-то попадалось в литературе, что изначально слово "дурак" было именем? Правда ли это? И как слово стало ругательным?

Comment: Этимологический словарь Крылова: ДУРАК - образовано от древнерусского прилагательного дурый – "глупый", которое является словом индоевропейской природы (в греческом thouros – "дикий", в древнепрусском durai – "дико").

Comment: Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва: ДУРАК. Искон. Суф. производное От дурый «глупый», того же корня, что лит. dùrti «колоть, жалить, ударить». Исходное значение — «ужаленный, искусанный», затем — «бешеный, сумасшедший, больной» (от укуса и т. д.) и далее — «дурной, глупый», ср. чешск. durný «глупый, сумасшедший», рус. диал. дурной «глупый, бешеный, сумасшедший, больной, дикий» и т. д.

Comment: Мирское имя Дурак восходит к аналогичному существительному со значением «глупый человек». Имя Дурак относится к охранительным именованиям. Согласно обычаю, существовавшему у славян, подобные имена присваивались детям с целью отвращения злых сил. Для того чтобы не искушать судьбу и отвести зло, ребенку давали имя со значением прямо противоположным тому, что ожидали или желали его родители. Так, нарекая младенца именем Дурак, родные хотели, чтобы он вырос смышленым, проворным в делах и успешным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Именем не было. Но от него, как и от других прозвищ, наименований по роду деятельности и имен образовалась фамилия ДУраков. Сын  кузнеца - Кузнецов (сын), сын Ивана  - Иванов, Дурака - Дураков.
В словаре Ожегова:
ДУРА́К
1. Глупый человек, глупец.

1. В старину: придворный или домашний шут.

Comment: Прозвище было почти что именем. Нецерковным, разумеется. В этом смысле и дурак могло быть именем, не обязательно по профессии. Шутов на руси было не так уж много (вспоминается только шут Балакирев), а вот дураками Россия матушка всегда славилась.